# SQL Creating backup table using EXCHANGE PARTITION

Tags: sql, oracle, backup, partitioning, partition

I want to make a backup of table `a1_crm_query` using `EXCHANGE PARTITION`. This table contains rows with different statuses like 'ERROR', 'NEW', or 'DONE', and it would be great if there will be another table (`a1_crm_query_LOG`) with statuses 'ERROR' and 'DONE' but my first table(`a1_crm_query`) will be with only 'NEW'.

First of all I create my table:

```
 CREATE TABLE ma_user.a1_crm_query (
       ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
       DATA VARCHAR2(200) 

    );
```

Then I create second table with partition.

```
CREATE TABLE ma_user.a1_crm_query_LOG (
       ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
       DATA VARCHAR2(200)
    )
    PARTITION BY LIST (DATA) (
       PARTITION DONE_STATUS VALUES ('DONE'),       
       PARTITION ERROR_STATUS VALUES ('ERROR')
       ) ;
```

then insert values into `a1_crm_query`:

```
INSERT INTO ma_user.a1_crm_query SELECT 1 , CAST('NEW' AS VARCHAR2(200)) FROM dual;
INSERT INTO ma_user.a1_crm_query SELECT 2 , CAST('DONE' AS VARCHAR2(200)) FROM dual;
INSERT INTO ma_user.a1_crm_query SELECT 3, CAST('ERROR' AS VARCHAR2(200)) FROM dual;
```

Now I want to create daily process which should move all rows with 'DONE' and 'ERROR' into table `a1_crm_query_LOG`, `a1_crm_query` should be only with 'NEW'.

I try to use `exchange partition`:

```
    ALTER TABLE ma_user.a1_crm_query_LOG EXCHANGE PARTITION ERROR_STATUS WITH TABLE ma_user.a1_crm_query WITHOUT VALIDATION;
ALTER TABLE ma_user.a1_crm_query_LOG EXCHANGE PARTITION DONE_STATUS WITH TABLE ma_user.a1_crm_query WITHOUT VALIDATION;
```

But after this `ERROR_STATUS` partition contains all rows with all statuses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create two temp tables (temp_error, temp_done) with ERROR and DONE data copied in them from the a1_crm_query table, then exchange partition with table temp_error and temp_done.

The issue you are facing is because of `WITHOUT VALIDATION`. Essentially you are telling Oracle that I have already validated the data being exchanged so Oracle will not validate it for you.

See [this link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9523105800346550404)

**Update: Approach 1** So this is what I would do.

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_ERROR
(       ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
        DATA VARCHAR2(200) );

CREATE TABLE TEMP_DONE 
(
  ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  DATA VARCHAR2(200) );

insert into TEMP_ERROR
select * from a1_crm_query
where data = 'ERROR';

insert into TEMP_DONE
select * from a1_crm_query
where data = 'DONE';

ALTER TABLE a1_crm_query_LOG EXCHANGE PARTITION ERROR_STATUS WITH TABLE TEMP_ERROR WITHOUT VALIDATION;

ALTER TABLE a1_crm_query_LOG EXCHANGE PARTITION DONE_STATUS WITH TABLE TEMP_DONE WITHOUT VALIDATION;

truncate table temp_error;
truncate table temp_done
```

**Update 2: Approach 2** If you can have a1_crm_query partitioned as well, then this approach might suit you best. You will need one interim table. No deletes or truncates required with this approach.

```
CREATE TABLE a1_crm_query (
   ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
   DATA VARCHAR2(200) 

)
    PARTITION BY LIST (DATA) (
   PARTITION DONE_STATUS VALUES ('DONE'),       
   PARTITION ERROR_STATUS VALUES ('ERROR'),
   PARTITION OTHER_STATUS VALUES (DEFAULT)
   ) ;

CREATE TABLE a1_crm_query_LOG (
   ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
   DATA VARCHAR2(200)
)
PARTITION BY LIST (DATA) (
   PARTITION DONE_STATUS VALUES ('DONE'),       
   PARTITION ERROR_STATUS VALUES ('ERROR')
   ) ;


INSERT INTO a1_crm_query SELECT 1 , 'NEW' FROM dual;
INSERT INTO a1_crm_query SELECT 2 , 'DONE'  FROM dual;
INSERT INTO a1_crm_query SELECT 3, 'ERROR' FROM dual; 
commit;       

CREATE TABLE interim
(       ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
       DATA VARCHAR2(200) );



ALTER TABLE a1_crm_query EXCHANGE PARTITION ERROR_STATUS WITH TABLE INTERIM WITHOUT VALIDATION;
ALTER TABLE a1_crm_query_LOG EXCHANGE PARTITION ERROR_STATUS WITH TABLE INTERIM  WITHOUT VALIDATION;

ALTER TABLE a1_crm_query EXCHANGE PARTITION DONE_STATUS WITH TABLE INTERIM WITHOUT VALIDATION;
ALTER TABLE a1_crm_query_LOG EXCHANGE PARTITION DONE_STATUS WITH TABLE INTERIM WITHOUT VALIDATION;
```

You must then rebuild the index on a1_crm_query

```
ALTER INDEX <index name> REBUILD;

select * from a1_crm_query;
select * from interim;
select * from a1_crm_query_LOG partition(ERROR_STATUS);
select * from a1_crm_query_LOG partition(done_STATUS)
```

Also See [this link](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/b/weblog/archive/2015/07/16/move-partitions-between-tables)

Comment: Hi, Akio! I should use only one _log table which should contans both statuses. I cant catch up why move ALL rows include 'NEW'

Comment: Akio, thanks, it works, but table a1_crm_query still has rows with 'ERROR' and 'DONE'. Frankly speaking, i dont see advantageous of this method. I thought that EXCHANGE PARTITION should replace INSERT-DELETE operation

Comment: @Jdzel you can delete ERROR and DONE records from a1_crm_query. I will post an alternative approach if you can have a1_crm_query partitioned as well.

Comment: Yes,it will be great if you post this. I can make a1_crm_query partitioned.

Comment: Akio, thanks, but after this exchanging i cant insert other rows with this statuses('ERROR') into a1_crm_query. I think it happens because of moving partition from this table. Should I add partition to a1_crm_query after exchanging?

Comment: aah! you have to rebuild the index ALTER INDEX SYS_C0020616 REBUILD; Replace the index name with yours. I have updated the answer above.